# Abrir Caja Registradora sin imprimir ticket C#

Tags: c#

actualmente tengo un código en C# que me ayuda a imprimir los tickets de mis ventas, funciona de maravilla, me abre el cajón al efectuar una venta, etc. Pero como ustedes sabrán, a veces necesitamos abrir la caja registradora sin registrar venta alguna, quisiera saber como hacerlo. Actualmente mi caja registradora esta conectada a mi impresora de tickets ("POS-58-Series"), que viene siendo una impresora de papel térmico. Mi pregunta es, hay alguna forma de configurar el boton de abrir el cajon de dinero sin que imprima nada mi impresora de tickets?

Actualmente tengo este código para la apertura del cajón al efectuar una impresión:

```
        ´´´public void AbreCajon()
        {
            //Estos tambien varian, tienen que ever el manual de la impresora para poner los correctos.
            linea.AppendLine("\x1B" + "p" + "\x00" + "\x0F" + "\x96"); //Caracteres de apertura cajon 0
                                                                       //linea.AppendLine("\x1B" + "p" + "\x01" + "\x0F" + "\x96"); //Caracteres de apertura cajon 1
        }            ´´´
```

Al poner eso mismo con otro nombre y fuera del resto del código de la impresion, no funciona.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Buscas los códigos para abrir el cajón desde código, o como configurar un boton físico para abrirlo?

Comment: Hola, @Pikoh, lo que pasa es que quiero hacer un boton en la interface del software de punto de venta que hice. Y que al presionar dicho boton abra la caja registradora sin necesidad de imprimir un ticket.

Comment: Prueba con los códigos `\x1B,\x70,\x00,\x32,\xFA`. Aunque depende del modelo de la impresora estos pueden variar, como bien pone en el comentario de tu código

Comment: Me podrías poner un ejemplo de cómo sería el codigo de apertura? Pues tal y como lo tengo ahí arriba no me funciona para abrirla, a menos que se imprima un ticket.

Comment: A ver, hace mucho que no uso este tipo de impresoras, asi que no recuerdo bien. Pero creo que simplemente tienes que hacer lo mismo que haces para imprimir un ticket, pero solo con una linea con los codigos que te he dicho en mi anterior comentario

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso..si simplemente mandas a imprimir con el contenido de `AbreCajon`, te debería abrir sin problemas

Comment: Intentare mañana que este en la tienda con esto ultimo que me comentaste, tiene sentido. En cuanto lo pruebe actualizo el post a ver que tal va. Gracias!